# TextView with different text lengths aligning next to horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-measure

I'm looking for efficient way (best XML only) to align two `TextView`s horizontally, smth like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opinion_author"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opinion_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

`opinion_date` will always have ~50-70dp length and must be fully visible aligned to right of `opinion_author`. author may have 0-255 chars and if too much for screen then ellipsize then.

In above when author is too long view is pushing out date view. Same situation when using `toRightOf`/`toLeftOf` when using `RelativeLayout`. Setting `layout_weight=1` for author keeping date sticked to right edge of parent viewgroup even when author have only few characters, so thre is a lot of space... I'm looking for a way, which aligns date to right of author even when it is ellipsized and ends with... I have few ideas how to solve it in Java (measuring views or textpaint, but all seems not so efficient...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:shrinkColumns="0">
<TableRow
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: and we have the winner! `TableLayout` and `shrinkColumns`, so obvious... thank you, dziękuję :)

Answer (score 0):

Give `android:weightSum = "1"` to your linear layout.
Give `android:maxWidth="250dp"` to opinion_author textview.
Give `android:layout_weight="0.3"` to opinion_date textview.

Something like given below.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opinion_author"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxWidth="250dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opinion_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: let author be "a" and date "27 october" - how the date will align next to "a" when "a" will occupy 0.7 of screen width ?! date must be aligned on end of author text, not to right of parent, which its written in question...

Comment: Use maxWidth attribute to opinion_author according to screen and remove layout_weight from it. It will work. Tested @snachmsm

Comment: no it will not work, you misunderstood the question. `opinion_date` will occupy 0.3 of screen width always, on tablet there will be a lot of unnecessary empty space. theoretically on smaller devices text for date might be too long

Comment: you can manage  your weights and width according to screen and according to text for date.

Comment: so you suggesting measuring how much text each author/date have. Java solution, not XML only, not so efficient. if Java is necessary needed then I will just use meauring views or texts, but solution with `TableLayout` (already accepted) is better, without any Java, working fine

Answer (score 0):

use weights!

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opinion_author"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/opinion_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

example:

`android:weightSum="3"` divies up into 3 parts

`android:layout_weight="2"` gives 2 parts to author

`android:layout_weight="1"` gives 1 part to date

play with the ratios till you're pleased!

(oh, `android:layout_width="0dp"` because `layout_weights` overrides them)

Comment: let author be "a" and date "27 october" - how the date will align next to "a" when "a" will occupy 2/3 of screen width ?! date must be aligned on end of author text, not to right of parent, which its written in question...

Answer (score 0):

set size in `android:layout_width`

like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opinion_author"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opinion_date"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

you can use `android:layout_weight` in LinearLayout child.

Comment: you have fixed width set, you didn't read the question? second `TextView` must align right of first, which must wrap text. visually they should look like one line

Comment: use `android:gravity="right"` in `LinearLayout` or you can use  java code.

Comment: then `opinion_author` will be also aligned to the right. whole text should align left, text itself and view